# Calculating time required for DynamoDB global table to replicate to a new region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB Global table already setup in us-west-2 and eu-west-1 regions. I want to add a new replica to us-east-1 region and want to calculate how much time will it take for the new replica in us-east-1 to have all the items from other regions. How to calculate the total time required for replication?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to restore from backup to a new table and test adding a region with global tables. I can tell you that each partition gets a worker and all replication is done in parallel. So it will be as fast as it can possibly be over the DynamoDB backplane.